# MySQL MyISAM - Insert takes much longer on LIVE environment than locally

Tags: mysql, performance, insert, myisam

I have a MyISAM table (call it A) with about 5 million rows, and a related MyISAM table B (which joins to A on the primary key) containing about 200 million rows. Table A has about 12 fields, mostly varchar, while table B contains 2 integer fields.

I originally created these tables locally on my Windows 8 machine (4GB RAM - SSD Hard disk) by running scripts which inserted the rows in chunks. I then mysqldump'ed the database to a .sql file.

I then transferred this .sql file to my LIVE environment (Windows Server 2008, 4GB RAM and non-SSD Hard disk). I restored the database from the dump file to a new database.

If I now perform an update of, say, 2000 rows (in A; and about 80 in B for each row inserted in A) in the local machine, it takes a couple of minutes (maybe 3 at most), whilst if I updated the same rows on the LIVE environment, it would take about 1.5 hours.

Why is there this significant difference? Both the local and LIVE machines have the same memory, and specs are very similar...Could it be down to the fact that my local machine has an SSD hard drive? Or did I need to perform an OPTIMIZE/ANALYZE table(s) (or anything else?) on the LIVE database after restoring it from the dump file?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Indeed, using SSD drive can significantly improve the IO operations of the server, sometimes between 20 and 100 times, compared to the standard mechanical hard drives.

Comment: Thanks bodi0...so you think that is the only reason? i.e. there is no need to optimize/analyze the tables after restoring from mysqldump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, using SSD drive can significantly improve the IO operations of the server, sometimes between 20 and 100 times.

Optimizing tables (and/or perform other software-level tuning) *can* help in many cases, hard to say in your particular situation (is/are the table(s) very fragmented, is the indexing used properly, etc...), but the bottleneck *is almost* always the hardware. However you can experiment, but I`m sure that the biggest difference will come if you replace HDD with SSD. I personally on my developer machine use Intel SSD and the difference in database IO are huge.

Read [this](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2739) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will consider replacing the disk.

Comment: However, I have read that using an SSD for a database server is not a good idea...as it will quickly wear down...

Comment: This depends on many factors, read the above article, they test a number of different devices and indeed it is important to choose the right one.